# A Retrospective Captor

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, password

Matthew woke up suddenly. He was in a dimly lit room -looked like an old office space. He stood up in a panic and looked around. He saw a few desks, ancient computers, yet no dust anywhere. He made a full turn and then saw a door with an exit sign above it. Matthew tried to open the door, but it was locked with a keyboard password. Shortly after, a voice echoed through the room.

"Hello, sir. You are the next of my victims. Matthew's your name, right? You may call me 'The Wise One."

Matthew said nothing. Too stunned to speak.

"Anyway, I have something special planned for you," the voice continued. "Of course, I will give you a chance to escape. If you enter the correct password to the exit, you will go free. You know enough to get out already, but I thought I would play the recordings of all my previous victims trying my test. Keep in mind they had different passwords to find."

Matthew heard the crackling of some speakers. Then the first recording began:

> **Wise One**: "Hello, sir. You are my first ever victim in my office! You're Collin, yes?"
>   **Collin**: "What is this? Who are you? Get me out of here! You have the wrong person!"
>   **Wise One**: "Calm down. My name is unimportant. Just don't screw up my office. I just got it and it's in mint-condition. If you want to survive, find the password to unlock the exit. I've told you everything you need. No more questions out of you."

The speakers cut out. "He didn't make it, by the way," says the Wise One. The next recording began:

> **Wise One**: "Hello, Mary. Are you ready to be my next victim? … It's okay, you can speak. … Alright then. You have a chance to save yourself if you type in the right password at the door. Here, this is for you."
>   **Mary**: "What -what is this?" 
>   **Wise One**: "Don't be silly, Mary. It's a rose. You look like you like flowers."
>   **Mary**: "Please, I'm not good at puzzles. Please pick someone else!" 
>   **Wise One**: "Take all the time you need. To give you another hand, here is the recording of my last victim, Colin. He had a different password, but maybe it will give you the clue to your survival."
>   **Mary**: "Please..."

The recording ended. "Believe it or not, Matthew, she figured it out," said the Wise One. The next recording started up:

> **Wise One**: "Greetings sir. You are my next victim in my office. Congratulations, Evan! Hmm...you don't seem that afraid."
>   **Evan**: "I'm not afraid of you, nor your disgusting 'office'. Who are you?". 
>   **Wise One**: "Time has not been friendly to my little chamber, I agree. My name would mean nothing to you."
>   **Evan**: "Any chance you'll give me the password to get out of here?"
>   **Wise One**: "Well, I've given you everything you need, but just to hold your hand further, how about I show you the recordings of my previous victims? They had different passwords, but they will certainly help you."
>   **Evan**: "Just give it to me now."
>   **Wise One**: "The more you speak, the less I want to give you hints. You can forget about the recordings I offered. Considering what you have to lose, you could show a little respect."

The speakers cut out again. "That's all of them," said the voice. "Keep in mind many details are meant to confuse you. I admit Colin and Evan had little chance of success. You get more mercy, so get to work. I have given you all my wisdom: use it well, Matthew.

Matthew heard the sound of his own recording end.

**What should Matthew type in as the password?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll be back to finish the puzzle, I'm almost out of

> sage

Because

> it's another word for a "Wise One"

The other answers are

> Collin: mint
>  Mary: rosemary
>  Evan: thyme

Because

> All the passwords are herbs and spices clued in by the Wise One ("mint-condition", "rose" + "Mary", "Time")

Comment: I only know it from the song lol

Comment: Nice answer! One point of further support for your reasoning is the fact that (rot 13) gur jvfr zna arire tnir uvf anzr gb gur bguref, rira tbvat nf sne nf fnlvat "zl anzr vf abg vzcbegnag" gb Pbyyva naq Rina, gurersber fhttrfgvat ubj uvf anzr vf vzcbegnag.